# What planets/systems are shown at the end of Return of the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

What systems are shown in the Celebration Sequence after the victory at Endor?

I think I saw Endor (twice), Tatooine, Bespin, Coruscant, and one or two others I didn't recognize.  I thought one might be Naboo.

Anyone recognize all of the worlds in this sequence?

Comment: Original theatrical, or Special Edition?

Comment: @DVK If it's original theatrical, the list is really short: Endor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the post-prequel special version (Hayden Christianson as the Anakin Force ghost) they are, in this order, Bespin, Tatooine, Naboo, and Coruscant, followed by an extended sequence of footage on Endor('s moon).